# Integrating Agora On-Premise Recording SDK with Python on Linux

Tags: python, linux, agora.io, agora

I'm trying to integrate the Agora On-Premise Recording SDK with Python on a Linux system, but I'm not sure how to proceed. I've tried using Boost,  Python, and ctypes, but I'm running into some issues.

Specifically, I'm trying to call the Agora SDK functions from Python code and record audio and video streams from an Agora client. I've compiled the Agora SDK as a shared library, but I'm not sure how to create Python bindings for the SDK functions.

Can anyone provide guidance on how to integrate the Agora On-Premise Recording SDK with Python on Linux? Are there any specific tools or libraries that would be useful for this task?